# Beginner Question (Oracle SQL) - Error with Varchar and SUM

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently using Oracle SQL Developer to learn PL/SQL at university. I'm facing a problem where I had to import a .csv file to a table and have to sum up all elements of a column called TIME (composed of minutes, seconds and milliseconds).

However, the column is consisted of VARCHAR and the format is as of below:

```
TIME
01:00.250
02:37.408
01:29.803
...
```

I keep getting an error, mostly because there are non-numeric characters (":" and ".") on the column and hence the sum cannot be done. I checked on other topics and saw people saying to use TO_CHAR, TO_DATE, but none solutions seems to work.

Is there a better/easy approach for this problem?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't have a `time` data type.  So, if you want to sum these, a simplish method is to convert the values to seconds:

```
select sum( to_number(substr(time, 1, 2)) * 60 +
            to_number(substr(time, 4)) 
          ) as seconds
```

To convert the value back to a string representation of a number:

```
select floor(seconds / 60) || ':' || (case when seconds < 10 then '0' || mod(seconds, 60) else '' || mod(seconds, 60) end) as mmss
from (select (sum( to_number(substr(time, 1, 2)) * 60 +
              to_number(substr(time, 4)) 
             ) as seconds
      . . .
     ) s
```

Comment: Be aware that `cast(substr(time, 4) as number)` fails on a time like `01:00.250` when the session's decimal separator is not the dot. In Germany for instance, we use the comma instead. You can use `TO_NUMBER` with an appropriate format mask instead, e.g. `to_number(substr(time, 4), '00.99999')`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried what you said but I got the error ORA-01722: invalid number.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . I prefer `to_number()` anyway.

Comment: Anyway, it seems I fixed it. :) Thanks, guys! Just another question, though: what if I want, for example, to convert to seconds, sum all the columns, and convert it back to the previous format (minutes, seconds and milliseconds)?

Comment: Hey guys, is it possible to sum these numbers after converting them and group by based on a unique ID? I was trying to do that, but it seems I cannot sum because of the "." that gets between the minutes and milliseconds. What would be an alternative to this problem?

Comment: @XD129 . . . Ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.